# Cannot find resource named 'VsTextBoxStyleKey'. Resource names are case sensitive. when debug vsix project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I'm using vs2019 to create a vsix project, and add a command item after project created, that's all I did. But when I debug the project, I whill get an exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> Exception: Cannot find resource named 'VsTextBoxStyleKey'. Resource names are case sensitive.

**Exception StackTrace:**

> at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)

**Exception BaseUri:**

> pack://application:,,,/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement;component/Themes/ThemedDialogStyles.xaml

I can't find this xaml from my disk, is it in a zip file? where I can find it.

**InnerException StackTrace:**

> at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
>
> at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>
> at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

Comment: infact, this exception will not break debug, and my code works fine. I just try to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Hourglass, does this issue also occur when you create a new vsix project and debug it? I tried it in my VS16.3.6 but can't reproduce it. So I suggest you check if the issue exists when debugging a new vsix project, so that we'll know where the issue comes from, VS IDE global setting or project itself.

Comment: Hi Lance Li-MSFT, maybe my computer environment gets trouble, copy my project to another computer, the exception never throw. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Apart from the computer environments, I suggest you can also try a VS repair or Update it to latest version, it helps when something is broken with IDE. If the issue still exists, hmm, like you said, maybe something wrong with PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and the error message, this issue may result from something broken in VS IDE. (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement;component` this indicates this is related to VS component)

So I think a [VS repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and then Update it to latest VS2019 16.3.7 can help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I just updated vs to 16.3.7 today :(, I'll try to repair vs, hope it works.

Comment: If so, you can try: 1. deleting the .vs folder in solution directory 2. [clean the vs cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md) (For VS2019, delete all componentcache folders under 16.x folders) 3.[Reset the experimental instance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-menu-command?view=vs-2019#clean-up-the-experimental-environment) 4. disable the third-party extensions your VS installed(restart VS to take effect). If all not works... Something wrong with the PC maybe :-(

Comment: repair vs fix the issue ;)