# How to customize the position of a menu item button in vsix extensibility project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menuitem, vsix, extensibility

I am creating an extension where I am trying to add a **menu item** containing two child **menu buttons**. This menu item must be shown as a top-level menu item but when I do that, The menu item added into the **Extensions** menu. I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603659/how-to-create-a-solution-right-click-top-level-menu-with-sub-level-buttonvisua) but the solution isn't working for me. There is no change in the position of menu even after making changes in priorities attributes. Following is code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>

  <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>

  <Commands package="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackage">
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop">
      </Group>
    </Groups>

    <Menus>
      <Menu guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" type="Menu">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS"/>
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>My Top Menu</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command1Id" type="Button">
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Changed 2</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command2Id" type="Button">
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Command2</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>

    <Bitmaps>
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\Ext1.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough"/>
    </Bitmaps>

  </Commands>

  <CommandPlacements>

    <CommandPlacement guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop" priority="0x0001">
      <Parent guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup"/>
    </CommandPlacement>

    <CommandPlacement guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command1Id" priority="0x0001" >
      <Parent guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop"/>
    </CommandPlacement>
    <CommandPlacement guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command2Id" priority="0x0002" >
      <Parent guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop"/>
    </CommandPlacement>
  </CommandPlacements>

  <Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackage" value="{5f20b1ae-835b-423f-89e1-a33f2e20a715}" />

    <GuidSymbol name="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" value="{2e60374a-c4f8-4d96-9bb6-301ab412846f}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroupTop" value="0x1021" />
      <IDSymbol name="Command1Id" value="0x0101" />
      <IDSymbol name="Command2Id" value="0x0102" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{512d3770-bde4-4353-a6c0-7138bbfffebe}" >
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2019 by default all top level extension menus go into the Extensions menu.

In VS **Customize** options - **Extensions menu** tab you can uncheck your menu to show at the top level:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this programmatically (by coding into the vsix project). So that user doesn't have to worry about placing.

Comment: @TanmayBairagi It is not possible to code into the vsix project.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Comment: My customize option is not showing "Extensions menu". Only "Toolbars" and "Commands" are available there.

Comment: @TanmayBairagi What is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: @TanmayBairagi "Extensions menu" is available starting with VS 2019 v16.4.0.

Comment: Okay. Mine is v16.3.x.x! Thanks! It would have been more helpful if I could add directly on top-level but now it is not possible. So it's fine! Thanks for guiding me!

Answer (score 2):

By default top level menu items, now appear under the Extensions menu. I believe this was done, to alleviate a lot of the clutter various extensions were adding to the top level menu bar.

However, there is a nifty extension in the VS Marketplace that allows you to selectively add them back to the top level menu bar.

[Extensions In Main Menu](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Evgeny.RestoreExtensions)

Issue was raised some time ago via the following communities thread:

[Get rid of new Extensions menu](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/435711/get-rid-of-new-extensions-menu.html)

Sincerely,

Comment: Thanks! this answer guided me for the solution.